# How can I create an environment with several variables for running a program in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, cgi

I'm working on a compiled program that shall be used as CGI-BIN.

```
cc -o script.cgi script.c library.a
```

I can test it via my web server (Apache) + web browser `http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi` or by command line `./script.cgi`.

When normally executed, the command line will show something like:

```
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Hello, World!</title>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
     <p>Some text that should depend on GET and
     other environmental variables.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the web browser will get the respective HTML page, and display it accordingly. So far so good.

The problem is that, when debugging, some errors seem to arise from environmental variables. I know I can provide one specific variable by running a command line such as:

```
QUERY_STRING='a=b&c=d' ./script.cgi
```

And, if I wasn't careful, I might get a core segmentation error. If this error occurs before I print the `Content-type` line, I will get a 500 error in my browser, and the core segmentation error message when testing from command line.

The 500 error make little room for debugging. I cannot check any `stderr` output. The command line approach allows me to see more specific error messages and debug information. But I am testing in a different environment than when in a web server/browser.

So how can I recreate the web server environment, with several environmental variables, and (if possible) removing environmental variables from the bash environment.

I'm okay with a bash script based solution, I don't need a one liner.

Comment: Do you know the full environment that you want to use, or you need to discover it as well?

Comment: You can check what would've been stderr in the error log for most versions (if not all..) of apache http server, no need to re-create the web server env. imo.

Comment: @Leon, I know what I need to put in the environment.

I have working C programs that can display the variables, or even something such as `<?php header('Content-type: text/plain;charser=utf-8'); print_r($_SERVER) ?>` would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple variables by just pitting them on the same line, like:

```
var1=foo var2=bar ./script.cgi
```

Or you can put this all in a file (say, `env.sh`), with contents like:

```
export var1=foo
export var2=bar
```

and then `source` the file before running the script:

```
source env.sh
./script.cgi
```

---

If you want to clear the inherited shell environment, you can use `env -i`.

```
env -i var1=foo var2=bar ./script.cgi
```

Or, if you want a script, make a script (say `script.sh`) like:

```
export var1=foo
...
./script.cgi
```

And call the script like:

```
env -i ./script.sh
```